# начало программирования - обучение

Tags: python-3.x

я только начинаю изучать программирование (в виде хобби-просто интересно) установил Питон 3.7.3 (64 bit) Shell, сделал вроде все по инструкции, после установки открыл окно и ввел первую команду как и рекомендовали:

"Например, введите следующее в интерактивную оболочку рядом с >>>приглашением:

> > > печать («Привет, мир!»)
> > >       После того, как вы напечатаете эту строку и нажмете ENTER , интерактивная оболочка должна отобразить это в ответ:
> > >
> > > print ('Привет, мир!') 
> > >       Привет, мир!"

но ответ мне последовал следующий:

">>> печать ("привет, мир!")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    печать ("привет, мир!")
NameError: name 'печать' is not defined"

что я не так сделал?

Comment: Не прочитали учебник.

Comment: Надо английское слово писать. print

Comment: возможно что то пропустил, подскажите к чему вернуться

Comment: xverizex спасибо, тогда почему в инструкции написано по русски

Comment: @333burgui333 - а где вы взяли инструкцию?

Comment: По-видимому автоперевод.  Читайте [офф. тутор.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: MiMEKiZ - https://automatetheboringstuff.com/

Comment: может с другого сайта надо обучаться?

Comment: @333burgui333, вы, я так понял, сделали гугловский автоперевод?

Comment: нет, я прописал как было прописано в инструкции обучения:  "Например, введите следующее в интерактивную оболочку рядом с >>>приглашением:


>>> печать («Привет, мир!»)"

Comment: @333burgui333, не понятно откуда вы взяли русский вариант кода -> "печать («Привет, мир!»)" . Ссылку которую вы дали ведет на англоязычный вариант книги, где в Главе 0 есть код: print('Hello world!').
Вы по этому сайту занимаетесь, или по его русской адоптации? Или вы переводите страницу переводчиком и так читаете?

Comment: MiMEKiZ, страница перевелась автоматически

Comment: MiMEKiZ, обучение идет с сайта Python

Comment: @333burgui333, страница перевелась автоматически благодарю Google Traslator, которому вы могли дать Разрешение на это. Но суть в следующем: переводчик перевел все команды, которые вам надо вводить в консоли на русский язык. Поэтому вы увидели  'печать («Привет, мир!»)' вместо правильного варианта 'print('Hello world!')'
Есть 3 выхода: 1) можно держать две вкладки открытыми, одна на русском(переведенная) и вторая на английском(не переведенная). Читать текст на русском, а исходный код брать с английской версии. 2) Найти эту книгу уже переведенную и адаптированную. 3) Читать в оригинале(на англ)

Comment: @333burgui333, автопереводчик просто перевел то, что не надо было переводить. Вот и у вас получилась из-за этого такая проблема. Интерпритатор языка питон не понимает русские оператора ('печать', 'если' и т.д.). Они все пишутся на английском

Comment: MiMEKiZ, спасибо, значит надо переучивать свой немецкий на английский ... а так это нормальная инструкция к обучению?

Comment: @333burgui333, всякий учебник, где объясняется синтаксис языка, для вас, в данный момент, будет нормальным. Всё остальное на ваше усмотрение. Нужны ли вам те или иные разделы, или нет

Comment: MiMEKiZ, спасибо